# 41 different balls are drawn from a bag

Tags: probability, combinatorics

41 different balls are drawn from a bag containing balls labelled 1,2,…,300. The probability that the number of balls drawn that are labelled with an odd number is larger than the number of balls drawn that are labelled with an even number can be expressed as ab where a and b are coprime positive integers. What is the value of a+b?

Comment: Do you mean $a/b$?  If so, $a/b = 1/2$ and so $a + b = 3$

Comment: Brillant again?

Comment: @Did I don't recognize the specific problem but the $a,b$ phrasing is an obvious indicator.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ be the event that more odd numbered balls are drawn than even numbered balls. Since we have $41$ balls, we cannot possible draw an equal number of even and odd balls. Therefore $P$ and $\overline{P}$ (the complement of $P$) exhaust the possibilities, i.e.
$$\Pr(P)+\Pr(\overline{P}) = 1$$
By symmetry, the two are equal. it follows that $$\Pr(P) =\frac{a}{b}= \frac{1}{2}\implies a+b=3$$

Comment: @leava_sinus You're welcome.